# Emberjs: Access controller dependency on a different namespace

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

In my ember application I want to have modules on different namespaces. I have an App Namespace and for each module there is an `App.ModuleName` namespace.

So far so good, I can access everything so far using `App/ModuleName/SomeResource` syntax. Now I have a controller that has a dependency on a controller in one of the module namespaces. I put up the controllers like this:

```
App.ModuleName.FooController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    fooVal: 42
});

App.SomeController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: ['App/ModuleName/Foo', 'bar']
});
```

That seem to work so far telling by ember not complaining that the needed controller doesn't exist.

Now, how do I acces the controller in my handlebars template? For the `bar` controller its easy, just using `controllers.bar.someProperty` but I cannot access the `App.ModuleName.FooController`. I tried:

```
{{controllers.App/ModuleName/Foo.fooVal}}
{{controllers.App.ModuleName.Foo.fooVal}}
{{controllers.Foo.fooVal}}
```

and so on, every combination I could think of but it didn't work. Is it possible (and how) to get this running? Can someone please enlighten me?

And by the way: Even on the controllers I use `needs` successfully, if I debug them (logging them into the console, from my code directly or with a handlebars helper) the `controllers` property is always `undefined`. Is there a way to check the needed controller references?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For everyone who is interested in how I solved the issue and what I tried and learned:**

I did some diggin in the code and tried a few things. I got the desired output using

a) A custom Handlebars helper that returns the property of the controller like this:

`{{ myhelper 'App.ModuleName.FooController' 'fooVal'}}`

with the following (quick and dirty) helper:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('myhelper', function(arg1, arg2, opts) {

    if (opts && opts['data']) {
        var ctrl = opts.data.properties[0];
        var prop = opts.data.properties[1];

        var controller = this.get('container').lookup('controller:' + ctrl.split('.').join('/'));
        if (controller) {
            return controller.get(prop);
        }
    }
});
```

The problem with this is, I couldn't get databinding to work, so if I changed my underlying model, the view didn't update.

b) Overriding the Controllers `init()` method to get the controller instance like this:

```
init: function() {
   this.module = this.get('container').lookup('controller:App/Module/Foo');
}
```

and then in the template:

`{{module.fooVal}}`

In the second way, also Databinding worked, but It didn`t feel correct, so I did some googlin and came across this post on the emberjs issue list:

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/683#issuecomment-5122333

As stated by tomdale, nested namespaces are not really something that is encouraged in ember, but multiple 'toplevel' namespaces are ok. So I decided to put up a toplevel namespace for every module and use a custom resolver to resolve them. Works like a charm now and feels like the right way to do it.

Any additional suggestions and comments about the pro's and con's of my second and final way of solving the problem would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, Ember's Container looks up stuff via the resolver. And it only looks for stuff on the application's namespace.

Some examples from the DefaultResolver [docs](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/2f8e0d88c82ce2f1aa08c2d6849c3ed4d7f8c6ba/packages/ember-application/lib/system/resolver.js#L52).

```
'controller:post' //=> App.PostController
'controller:posts.index' //=> App.PostsIndexController
'controller:blog/post' //=> Blog.PostController
'controller:basic' //=> Ember.Controller
```

To achieve what you need you will need to provide a custom `Resolver` that looks up stuff in the different namespace when creating the Application.

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  resolver: MyNewResolver
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The `DefaultResolver` resolves `App/ModuleName/Foo` to `App.ModuleName.FooController` which is correct, so that doesn't seem to be the problem. The problem is that I can't figure out the name to access it in my Handlebars Template. Any ideas?

Comment: Interesting. I was under the impression the naming convention was quite strict. Post(model) -> PostRoute -> PostController -> PostView -> post or post/index(when implicit). Try turning on LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS. It will print out what template Ember is looking up when rendering a view.